# Error with command: 'rails new "project name"'

Tags: ruby, windows, ruby-on-rails-3

```
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Fetching gem metadata from ............
Fetching additional metadata from 
Resolving dependencies...

Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read
server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.org/gems/rake-
10.4.2.gem)
An error occurred while installing rake (10.4.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.4.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: Please explain your situation. Just posting the error message doesn't give people all the information they need to help.

Comment: Are you connected to the internet via a proxy?

Comment: Have you tried my steps below?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue and i have solved it by upgrading to latest version,

1. Download latest `rubygems` package from [rubygems](https://rubygems.org/pages/download)
2. Unpack at your specific path like `D:\Ruby\RubyGems`.
3. Bring up your command line by following this `Win + R, cmd , Enter`
4. Go to the directly where you unpacked `rubygems` package to: `cd D:\Ruby\RubyGems`
5. Run `ruby setup.rb`

Let me know if it solve your problem.